# Need help creating asynchronous data scraper in WordPress

Tags: plugins, ajax, wpdb, http-api, wp-remote-get

I need some help on a data scraping script I've been working on. I want to create a script through which content can be extracted from a page.

I fetched the page via `wp_remote_get()` and `wp_remote_retrieve_body()`. Using the DOMDocument() class, I was able to target the specific elements and upload them in database afterwards. Please tke a look at the following code -

```
$url = "https://www.myexampleurl.com/page-to-be-scraped";

 $data = wp_remote_get( $url,
        array(
            'timeout'   =>  60
        )
    );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $data );

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $body );

    $xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
    $xpath->registerNamespace( 'm', $url );

    //The page has a center tag, believe it or not
    $center = $dom->getElementsByTagName('center')->item(0);

    //Targeting all links
    $query = '//a';
    $entries = $xpath->query( $query, $center );

    $count = 1;
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {

        //The target elements have 'data-lightbox' attribute
        $attr = $entry->attributes->getNamedItem( 'data-lightbox' );

        //Uploading the sibling attribute to 'data-lightbox'
        if ( !empty( $attr ) ) {

            //The data fetched is uploaded to dtabase using this function
           my_upload_file_by_url( $attr->previousSibling->nodeValue );

        }
    }
```

Also tried using Ajax -

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_crawl_content', 'crawl_content');
function crawl_content() {
$url = "https://www.myexampleurl.com/page-to-be-scraped";

 $data = wp_remote_get( $url,
        array(
            'timeout'   =>  60
        )
    );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $data );

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $body );

    $xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
    $xpath->registerNamespace( 'm', $url );

    //The page has a center tag, believe it or not
    $center = $dom->getElementsByTagName('center')->item(0);

    //Targeting all links
    $query = '//a';
    $entries = $xpath->query( $query, $center );

    $count = 1;
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {

        //The target elements have 'data-lightbox' attribute
        $attr = $entry->attributes->getNamedItem( 'data-lightbox' );

        //Uploading the sibling attribute to 'data-lightbox'
        if ( !empty( $attr ) ) {

            //The data fetched is uploaded to dtabase using this function
           my_upload_file_by_url( $attr->previousSibling->nodeValue );

        }
    }


//jQuery Code
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Make the call on submitting a form
    jQuery('#crawlForm').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        crawlRequest();
    });

    function crawlRequest() {

        var data = {
            action: 'my_crawl_content'
        }

        jQuery.post(
            ajaxurl,
            data,
            function( response ) {
               jQuery('#crawlForm').append( response );
            }
        );
    }
});
```

AJAX throws a timeout error.

Also used `wp_schedule_single_event` to schedule the script -

```
wp_schedule_single_event( time() + MINUTE_IN_SECONDS * 15, 'my_crawl_event' );
add_action( 'my_crawl_event', 'crawl_content' );
function crawl_content() {
$url = "https://www.myexampleurl.com/page-to-be-scraped";

 $data = wp_remote_get( $url,
        array(
            'timeout'   =>  60
        )
    );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $data );

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $body );

    $xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
    $xpath->registerNamespace( 'm', $url );

    //The page has a center tag, believe it or not
    $center = $dom->getElementsByTagName('center')->item(0);

    //Targeting all links
    $query = '//a';
    $entries = $xpath->query( $query, $center );

    $count = 1;
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {

        //The target elements have 'data-lightbox' attribute
        $attr = $entry->attributes->getNamedItem( 'data-lightbox' );

        //Uploading the sibling attribute to 'data-lightbox'
        if ( !empty( $attr ) ) {

            //The data fetched is uploaded to dtabase using this function
           my_upload_file_by_url( $attr->previousSibling->nodeValue );

        }
    }
```

Also, `$dom->loadHTML( $body )` throws an error as follows -

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 241 in /Users/apple/Sites/indidev/wp-content/plugins/crawler/crawler.php on line 56
```

Any guidance in the right direction is highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know why that error, but as for your AJAX and WP-Cron/`wp_schedule_single_event` code, can you add it to your post? And be as detailed as possible, e.g. how and when did you call your AJAX, and what didn't work well with your `wp_schedule_single_event` code? Have you tried using WP-CLI to run your scraping script?

Comment: Edited the post. wp_schedule_single_event works the best but it starts a new crawl on every page refresh.